# Creating a Zip then copying folders to it

Tags: vbscript, zip

I'm trying to create a zip file, then copy three folders into it. I get the error on line 33 char 1, error state object required, I have searched and googled but just can't seem to either understand what I'm reading or understand what I really need to search for. Anyhow, here is my code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder1, objFolder2, objFolder3, FolderToZip, ziptoFile, FolderGroup
Dim ShellApp, eFile, oNewZip, strZipHeader
Dim ZipName, Folder, i, Zip, Item
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder1 = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog")
Set objFolder2 = objFSO.GetFolder ("C:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs")
Set objFolder3 = objFSO.GetFolder ("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs")
'For Each efile In objFolder.Files
'  If DateDiff("d",eFile.DateLastModified,Now) >= 2 Then
'    objFSO.MoveFile eFile, "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Test2\"
'  End If
'Next
Wscript.Sleep 2000
Set oNewZip = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\win7tools\testing script.zip", 8, True)
strZipHeader = "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6)
For i = 0 To 17
  strZipHeader = strZipHeader & Chr(0)
Next
oNewZip.Write strZipHeader
oNewZip.Close
Set oNewZip = Nothing
WScript.Sleep 5000
FolderGroup = Array(objFolder1,objFolder2,objFolder3)

FolderToZip = "FolderGroup"
ZipToFile = "C:\Win7tools\Test Script.zip"
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Zip = ShellApp.NameSpace(ZipToFile)
'Set Folder = ShellApp.NameSpace(FolderToZip)
ShellApp.NameSpace(FolderGroup).CopyHere Zip.NameSpace(ZipToFile)
WScript.Sleep 10000

set ShellApp = Nothing
set FolderToZip = Nothing
set ZipToFile = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ```
> retVal = Shell.NameSpace(
>   vDir
> )
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *vDir* [in]
>
> Type: **Variant**
>
> The folder for which to create the **Folder** object. This can be a string that specifies the path of the folder or one of the **ShellSpecialFolderConstants** values. Note that the constant names found in **ShellSpecialFolderConstants** are available in Visual Basic, but not in VBScript or JScript. In those cases, the numeric values must be used in their place.

The `NameSpace` method expects either a string with a path or the integer value of one of the [`ShellSpecialFolderConstants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not an array of `Folder` objects. Also you got the order wrong. The object on which you call the `copyHere` method is the zip file. The argument is what you want to copy to the zip file (a path string should do just fine here). Plus, the name of the zip file you create is different from the name of the zip file you try to add the folders to.

Change your code to this:

```
folder1 = "C:\Windows\Temp\SMSTSLog"
folder2 = "C:\Windows\System32\CCM\Logs"
folder3 = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CCM\Logs"
zipfile = "C:\Win7tools\Test Script.zip"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.OpenTextFile(zipfile, 2, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) _
  & String(18, Chr(0))

Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set zip = ShellApp.NameSpace(zipfile)
zip.CopyHere folder1
zip.CopyHere folder2
zip.CopyHere folder3

WScript.Sleep 10000
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works great, now I get to write how to check the folder if there are files, if so then zip, if not then skip. Thanks again!

Comment: as we are using CopyHere method ,if file already available in the zip folder then windows ask for file replacement, how can we by pass windows file replacement dialog box?

Comment: @ParthAkbari Please post a question of your own.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, i have reached to question limit

Comment: Hello, I had a equal requirement and your code helped. Only thing is that I have to make a .Sleep() after every copy to make it work or I get error messages. Best would be a "waituntildone" flag but can not find any...

Answer (score 1):

WinZip has a Command Line Interface.  You might have to download and install it depending on your version:  http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm

The below is a test script that works for WinZip version 9.0 if it helps.

```
Const WinZip = "C:\Program Files\WinZip9.0\wzzip.exe"  'WinZip Version 9.0

BasePath = "C:\Path\To\Folders\"

strZipFilePath = BasePath & "Test.zip"
strArchiveMe = BasePath & "Folder_A"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not objFSO.FileExists(WinZip) Then
    MsgBox "WinZip (wzzip.exe) Does Not Exist"
    WScript.Quit
End If

'''// For Below Command - Change "-a" TO "-mu" To Auto Delete The file After Zip Is Created
'''// For Below Command - Change "-yb" TO "-ybc" To Answer YES To all Promps and not Terminate Operation
strcommand = Chr(34) & WinZip & Chr(34) & " -a -yb " & Chr(34) & strZipFilePath & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & strArchiveMe & Chr(34)
objShell.Run strcommand, 1, True
```

The command format is:

```
winzip [action] [options] [Zip Path] [Path to file/folder to zip]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I really appreciate the feed back and the community here.

Comment: @user2868186 - Glad to hear it.  If it works out for you, don't forget to accept the answer.  Let me know if you run into any issues.